# How to refer more specifically in Tufte-style handout

Tags: citing, tufte

This question may be open-ended and have many solutions....

---

***Usual Style***

Consider the following simple document

[image]

which is generated by the following code.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@book{golub13,
  author = {Golub, Gene H. and van Loan, Charles F.},
  edition = {4th},
  title = {Matrix Computations},
  year = 2013,
  publisher = {JHU Press}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\begin{document}
It is well-known that the eigenvalues of $A + vv^T$ interlace those of
$A$ \cite[Theorem 8.1.8]{golub13}.

\bibliography{bib}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the `cite` command takes an optional argument 'Theorem 8.1.8' to give more information about the reference. I want the reader to look at exactly Theorem 8.1.8 in the book so that they do not have to skim through the entire textbook of more than 700 pages to see which part is about eigenvalue interlacing.

---

***Tufte Style***

I can do something similar in Tufte-style document,

[image]

which is generated by the following.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@book{golub13,
  author = {Golub, Gene H. and van Loan, Charles F.},
  edition = {4th},
  title = {Matrix Computations},
  year = 2013,
  publisher = {JHU Press}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\begin{document}
It is well-known that the eigenvalues of $A + vv^T$ interlace those of
$A$.\cite{golub13}

\nobibliography{bib}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot give more specific information because the tufte-handout does not support `cite` command with an optional argument. What is the best way to do this?

One simplest answer can be just using a footnote on the side line and writing something like the following one-by-one by hand.

```
Refer to Theorem 8.1.8 in Golub and van Loan's Matrix Computations.
```

But I still want to use LaTeX's bibliography management system. I welcome any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Add `nobib` to the document options:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@book{golub13,
  author = {Golub, Gene H. and van Loan, Charles F.},
  edition = {4th},
  title = {Matrix Computations},
  year = 2013,
  publisher = {JHU Press}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\begin{document}
It is well-known that the eigenvalues of $A + vv^T$ interlace those of
$A$ \cite[Theorem 8.1.8]{golub13}.

\bibliography{bib}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}

\end{document}
```

[image]